# Manter o hint do campo visível ao começar a digitar

Tags: android

Em alguns aplicativos como os mostrados abaixo, o hint não é ocultado ao se começar a escrever dentro do campo. No Gmail, parece que os campos **De** e **Para** não usam hint são uma combinação de layout + estilo. O segundo exemplo, é do aplicativo Organizze que parece não utilizar a abordagem do Gmail, e sim o hint. Como implementar essa característica?

**Gmail:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Organizze:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Olhando o app do Gmail notei duas situações: 1) O `De` e `Para` não são hints do `EditText`, podem ser `TextViews` que ficam fora do campo. Você consegue montar um layout que tenha essa funcionalidade bem fácil com um `LinearLayout`. 2) O `Assunto` e fica ocultado quando você começa a digitar. No Material Design, existe o conceito de `Float Label` que pode ser visto [aqui](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/text-fields.html#text-fields-floating-labels), e que existe uma implementação na biblioteca `design library` chamada de `TextInputLayout` que pode lhe ajudar.

Comment: @Wakim, se o `De` e o `Para` tiverem sido implementados conforme você pensa, fizeram uma baita gambiarra para posicioná-los.

Comment: Não necessariamente, esse tipo de layout é muito comum: `LinearLayout horizontal` com 3 filhos: `TextView` + `EditText` sem background + `ImageButton`. Não vejo nenhuma gambiarra, é apenas uma forma de organizar um "formulário".

Comment: @Wakim, você está certo. Olhei de forma mais atenta o layout do Gmail. Não há gambiarra foi estruturado da forma como você imaginou.

Comment: Interessante @Wakim mas os textViews estão aparentemente ocupando as mesmas posições(dentro) do InputText, observe a linha abaixo que passa abaixo do textview é a linha do inputText, me parece mais um inputText customizado. Olhando o app `Organizze`

Comment: @Skywalker, esse caso é mais interessante sim, mas os comentários que fiz foram para o caso do Gmail, o do Organizze veio depois. Eu acho que daria pra implementar usando um tipo de `TextDrawable` e setando como `drawableLeft|drawableStart` do `EditText`.

Comment: Então depois que percebi que o comentário era sobre o gmail, Achei interessante esse input do `Organizze`

Answer (score 4):

Use **TextInputLayout** é do Google. Quando o usuário digita algo, o **hint** sobe e vira **title**.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/nome"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/texto_nome"
        android:inputType="text"/>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```